# Does using volatile to publish immutable objects are safe?

Tags: java, concurrency, volatile, java.util.concurrent

Recently I read "Java concurrency in practice"
    Section --> "3.4.2 Example: Using volatile to publish immutable objects".

However; I can't quietly understand it.
Here is the situation!

Immutable object is:

```
@Immutable
class OneValueCache {
    private final BigInteger lastNumber;
    private final BigInteger[] lastFactors;
    public OneValueCache(BigInteger i, BigInteger[] factors) {
        lastNumber = i;
        lastFactors = Arrays.copyOf(factors, factors.length);
    }
    public BigInteger[] getFactors(BigInteger i) {
        if (lastNumber == null || !lastNumber.equals(i))
            return null;
        else
            return Arrays.copyOf(lastFactors, lastFactors.length);
    }
}
```

Suppose we have a servlet like this

```
public class MyServlet {
private volatile OneValueCache immutableValue;
.
.

public void service(){
            .
            // what this function do : gets value from immutable object increments its
            // value and creates new Immutable object and put it back.
            // 
            .
    immutableValue = new OneValueCache( lastNumber, lastFactor[]);
    .
    .
    .
}
.
.
.
}
```

According the book MyServlet is Thread Safe because it publishes Immutable Object with volatile keyword!

However I think there is a problem here!

Suppose:

Thread 1 in time 0 read the values from immutableValue to its stack var;

Thread 2 in time 0 read the values from immutableValue to its stack var;

Thread 1 in time 1 increment the values in stack variable and create new OneValueCache 
          object -which is immutable - and put it in immutableValue field variable;

Thread 2 in time 2 increment the values in stack variable and create new OneValueCache
          object -which is immutable - and put it in immutableValue field variable;

This way we lost Thread1 update so there is no ThreadSafty here!

On the contrary the book says:

**"
This combination of an immutable holder object for
multiple state variables related by an invariant, and a volatile reference used to
ensure its timely visibility, allows VolatileCachedFactorizer to be thread-safe
even though it does no explicit locking.
"**

Can anyone help me what am I missing here?

p.s: to more clarify, I know data consistency is held here. we can not have invalid OneValueCache state. but there is a chance for lost update here as my thread sequence shows. so the class is not thread safe!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Immutability implies thread safety because once created no thread can modify it, so value will remain consistent across threads.

In the above example "private volatile OneValueCache immutableValue" can hold only one value at a time , so if thread 1 updated first and then thread 2 updated reference value then the last value will represented by "onevaluecache" and update of Thread 1 will be lost as you are storing only one reference value.

At no point in steps mentioned by you state of OneValueCache is inconsistent, so it is thread safe.

EDIT: Some of Cases where state will not be consistent are:

1. If immutableValue variable was not volatile then each thread will store its own copy, which means cache will not work properly.
2. If OneValueCache  class was mutable then mutiple threads will look to change its value simultaneously which means state will not be consistent hence not thread safe.

Comment: I underestand in respect of data consistency we are safe here but we could have lost update here which make the class not threadsafe!!

Comment: Its a singlevaluecache and only last update can stay!! all earlier updates will have to be garbage collected, isn't it. I dont understand what do you mean by lost update

Comment: Suppose singlevaluecache whitout syncornyzation incrementing singlevaluecach value may lead some lost update

Comment: We are never incrementing singlevaluecache[Its Immutable], we simply replace the reference. The last reference update is value which will reflect.

Comment: By incrementing i mean getting value of SingleValueCach increment it, constructing new SingleValueCash with new value and put it back! ( in general any manipulation MUST involve getting value from immutable Obj and create new Immutable Object from new values- Operation which i believe is not thread safe)

Comment: Ok , i get your point now. Nowhere in this cache they talk about increment the value stored in SingleValueCache thats a completely separate issue and must be synchronized [should be handled separately]. Point mentioned in this implementation is that because cache stores an immutable object its thread safe. Now imagine if this was not immutable then one user might be calling getValue and another modifying SAME OBJECT, this is not thread safe. With current impl., get and modify of SAME object can't happen at same time due to immutability.

Comment: Absolutely! So this strategy (replacing mutable object with Immutable) doesn't make sense. We have to always get the value from Immutable Object create new Immutable Object from new value and put the new one back! and it is not thread safe operation! but the book said the class is thread safe! and this was where i can't understand.

Comment: My friend ... thts why we have volatile!! Thread safety is not broken. If immutableValue was not volatile then each thread will have its own cached value and this cache will not work.

Comment: Just wanted to add another point that, it will not be thread safe if get and reference change happen at same time. This will be prevented by Volatile, hence making it thread safe.

Comment: Thanks @loki. to sum up, because of volatile, getting and changing reference of Immutable is thread safe but Increment value inside it (by creating new object) is a horse of different color and should handle separately! am i correct?

Comment: Absolutely. If this object was mutable then this implementation was not thread safe.

Comment: Immutability doesn't imply thread safety. Either the object needs to use safe publication (e.g. through a volatile variable,  a lock etc).  Or the object needs to rely on initialization safety. Initialization safety is a fallback strategy so that objects that are published without safe publication, will not cause for example security problems. So if neither of these mechanisms is used, then an immutable object, doesn't need to guarantee thread safety.

Answer (score 2):

volatile keyword ensures that threads pull latest version of immutable object from shared memory rather than from a local cache (ex: cpu register, stack, etc.). However, if two threads read, modify and publish the object simultaneously to the same volatile variable, changes from one thread can get lost. To support such use cases, it is better to use mutex like synchronized keyword or a read-write lock.

Typically, you would use volatile when only one thread publishes updated immutable objects to that volatile variable, but multiple threads read from it. In such cases, you do not worry about thread interference.

In Java, threads can cache (partial/full) copies of non-volatile variables into their own "reserved" memory space (ex: cpu register, stack, etc.). volatile keyword can be seen as a way to bypass these caches and ensure that thread gets fresh copy of object when you access and only when you access the volatile variable.

Comment: Caches on modern processors are always coherent; they are the source of truth. Cache coherence is taken care of by the cache coherence protocol. RAM is just a spill bucket for whatever doesn't fit into the cache and can be completely out of sync with what is in cache. Volatile ensures 3 things: atomicity, visibility and ordering.